# Mapping a dataframe (with NA) to an n by n adjacency matrix (as a data.frame object)

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, adjacency-matrix

I have a three-column `dataframe` object recording the bilateral trade data between 161 countries, the data are of dyadic format containing 19687 rows, three columns (reporter (`rid`), partner (`pid`), and their bilateral trade flow (`TradeValue`) in a given year). `rid` or `pid` takes a value from 1 to 161, and a country is assigned the same `rid` and `pid`. For any given pair of (`rid`, `pid`) in which `rid` =/= `pid`, `TradeValue`(`rid`, `pid`) = `TradeValue`(`pid`, `rid`).

The data (run in R) look like this:

```css
#load the data from dropbox folder
library(foreign)
example_data <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/hf0ga22tdjlvdvr/example_data.csv?dl=1")

head(example_data, n = 10)
   rid pid TradeValue
1    2   3        500
2    2   7       2328
3    2   8    2233465
4    2   9      81470
5    2  12     572893
6    2  17     488374
7    2  19    3314932
8    2  23      20323
9    2  25         10
10   2  29    9026220
```

The data were sourced from [UN Comtrade database](https://comtrade.un.org/), each `rid` is paired with multiple `pid` to get their bilateral trade data, but as can be seen, not every `pid` has a numeric id value because I only assigned a `rid` or `pid` to a country if a list of relevant economic indicators of that country are available, which is why there are `NA` in the data despite `TradeValue` exists between that country and the reporting country (`rid`). The same applies when a country become a "reporter," in that situation, that country did not report any `TradeValue` with partners, and its id number is absent from the `rid` column. (Hence, you can see `rid` column begins with 2, because country 1 (i.e., Afghanistan) did not report any bilateral trade data with partners). A quick check with summary statistics helps confirm this

```css
length(unique(example_data$rid))
[1] 139
# only 139 countries reported bilateral trade statistics with partners
length(unique(example_data$pid))
[1] 162
# that extra pid is NA (161 + NA = 162)
```

Since most countries report bilateral trade data with partners and for those who don't, they tend to be small economies. Hence, I want to preserve the complete list of 161 countries and transform this `example_data` dataframe into a 161 x 161 adjacency matrix in which

1. for those countries that are absent from the `rid` column (e.g., `rid` == 1), create each of them a row and set the entire row (in the 161 x 161 matrix) to 0.
2. for those countries (`pid`) that do not share `TradeValue` entries with a particular `rid`, set those cells to 0.

For example, suppose in a 5 x 5 adjacency matrix, country 1 did not report any trade statistics with partners, the other four reported their bilateral trade statistics with other (except country 1). The original dataframe is like

```css
rid pid TradeValue
2 3 223
2 4 13
2 5 9
3 2 223
3 4 57
3 5 28
4 2 13
4 3 57
4 5 82
5 2 9
5 3 28
5 4 82
```

from which I want to convert it to a 5 x 5 adjacency matrix (of `data.frame` format), the desired output should look like this

```css
 V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 223 13 9
3 0 223 0 57 28
4 0 13 57 0 82
5 0 9 28 82 0
```

And using the same method on the `example_data` to create a 161 x 161 adjacency matrix. However, after a couple trial and error with `reshape` and other methods, I still could not get around with such conversion, not even beyond the first step.

It will be really appreciated if anyone could enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot read the dropbox file but have tried to work off of your 5-country example dataframe -

```
country_num = 5

# check countries missing in rid and pid
rid_miss = setdiff(1:country_num, example_data$rid)
pid_miss = ifelse(length(setdiff(1:country_num, example_data$pid) == 0), 
                                     1, setdiff(1:country_num, example_data$pid))

# create dummy dataframe with missing rid and pid
add_data = as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, list(rid_miss, pid_miss, NA)))
colnames(add_data) = colnames(example_data)

# add dummy dataframe to original
example_data = rbind(example_data, add_data)

# the dcast now takes missing rid and pid into account
mat = dcast(example_data, rid ~ pid, value.var = "TradeValue")

# can remove first column without setting colnames but this is more failproof
rownames(mat) = mat[, 1]
mat = as.matrix(mat[, -1])

# fill in upper triangular matrix with missing values of lower triangular matrix 
# and vice-versa since TradeValue(rid, pid) = TradeValue(pid, rid)
mat[is.na(mat)] = t(mat)[is.na(mat)]

# change NAs to 0 according to preference - would keep as NA to differentiate 
# from actual zeros
mat[is.na(mat)] = 0
```

Does this help?

Comment: Just a quick touch base. Thanks so much for your response, I will look at your code after get back from work and Dropbox folder link has been updated.

Comment: I applied your data to my data, but it didn't work, because `add_data` is of different length than `example_data`, the former does not have the third column (`TradeValue`).

Comment: It's because in my `example_data`, the `pid` contains complete list of all country id, if you check that with `pid_miss = setdiff(1:country_num, example_data$pid)`, `length(pid_miss)` is 0. Putting `pid_miss` into `list(rid_miss, pid_miss, NA)` will create an `add_data` object of only 2 columns, which is not of the same length as `example_data`.

Comment: I know it is a big dataset but can you `dput` it? I am still unable to access the dropbox file, and I need it to understand the data better. Your 5 x 5 example had `1` missing from both `rid` and `pid` and so I assumed that was your dataset was like.

Comment: Thanks again for your response, but the dropbox link should work by now. The data contain 15602 rows, so it's hard to `dput` here.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll take a look this weekends and get back to you asap.

Comment: Hi, the second step `pid_miss = ifelse(length(setdiff(1:country_num, example_data$pid) == 0), 1, setdiff(1:country_num, example_data$pid))` generated an `NA` because there's no missing value from 1:161 in `example_data$pid`, after `rbind`-ing with `example-data` and `dcast`, this would create a 161 by 162 matrix (i.e., 161 + `NA`), which is not a symmetric matrix. I've tried omitting the `pid_miss` in the `add_data` step, but this returns an error message. However, I do think your code should work, just some dimensional issues I haven't been able to figure out.